Did Oppenheimer climb Trinity's steel tower during the storm?
Did Oppenheimer actually climb to the top of Trinity's tower in a bad storm to give the bomb a final inspection? Is this documented in the book on which the movie is based?

Yes and no. American Prometheus (on which the film was largely based) states that Oppenheimer did personally inspected the 'gadget' one last time, but this was before the storm had arrived. It was windy and overcast, but no thunder or lightning. He inspected it in the late afternoon.

In the late afternoon [July 15th], as thunderclouds moved in, Oppie drove to the Trinity tower for one last look at his “gadget.” Alone, he climbed the tower and inspected his creation, an ugly metal globe studded with detonator plugs. Everything seemed in order, and after surveying the landscape he climbed down, got back into his vehicle and drove over to the McDonald Ranch, where the last of the men who had assembled the gadget were packing up their gear. A violent storm was brewing.
American Prometheus

Lansing Lamont's Day of Trinity places Oppenheimer's last inspection at around 4pm, before the arrival of the actual storm, and around twelve hours before the detonation.

About four o'clock [PM], as thunderheads began moving into the area, Ken Greisen climbed the tower. He carried a device called the informer. He would rig it to the detonators on the bomb and it would tell him what had gone wrong if the detonation failed. Inside the shed at the top of the tower he picked his way over coils of wire and carefully connected each of the sixty-four detonators to the informer. The north side of the shack, facing the biggest array of instruments and cameras, was uncovered, and Greisen could look out and see the storm clouds scudding in over the Chupadera Mesa and the Oscuras. Lightning, he thought—what if it should hit the tower and detonate the bomb? He laughed to himself. He could just as easily be blown to bits by the cubic inch of explosive in the tiny detonator he held in his hand. Another scientist climbed the tower after Greisen had left. Robert Oppenheimer wanted to see for himself that nothing had been neglected in the bomb's final toilet. Perhaps, too, he wanted to feel the Gorgon's head one last time and stare it in the face with all its barbarous accouterments. Perhaps, more than anything else, he wanted to be alone where he could think, high above the busy desert with just the wind and the bomb for companions.

At least one man did stay on the tower overnight, Donald (Don) Hornig. He was the last to evacuate Zero tower, an hour or two before the bomb was detonated.






Thanks so much Valorum. I'm definitely going to have to read American Prometheus! Again, thank you for the details!

@edhuff - If you're interested in the specifics of the bomb, I'd recommend The Making of the Atomic Bomb by Richard Rhodes: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Making_of_the_Atomic_Bomb

I have read the Rhode text — a long but great book! Thanks. Prometheus is in the queue!

One last question having watched the movie again: I'm assuming Hitler did not say to Einstein's face that quantum physics is, "Jewish science." If not, was anything remotely close to that sentiment conveyed in person to Einstein?

@edhuff - Hitler never met Einstein, period.

Thanks. . . . as I suspected!
